# Writing log files to SSD

Tags: ssd, .net-framework

We have an application that does a LOT of logging. The medium we log to is SLC SSD drives however we are starting to see some failures in the field. We could turn logging off (we do), have log levels (we have) however sometimes an engineer turns on logging to diagnose a fault and forgets to turn it off which results in a failed SSD some time later.

Looking at the logging code, we save the log entry to a queue and every 5 seconds, iterate over the collection and use File.AppendAllText to write the line to the file.

According to MSDN this writes to the file then closes it.

What would be a better regime to use to achieve the same functionality but prevent (or reduce) damage to the SSD?

Would it be better to open a FileStream at software start, write to the stream during use and close before the software quits? How would this alleviate the situation at the disk level? What processes are involved and how is this better than opening the file and closing it immediately. Using FileStream 'feels' better but I need a more concrete rationale before making changes.

Maybe there is a better way that we haven't considered.

Comment: I'm surprised you are running into failing SSDs in this day in age - Wear leveling and trim should of alleviated most of the problem. You aren't running a raid, are you? Have you considered switching to SLC drives?

Comment: No raid. Already am using SLC. MLC should read SLC above. Have edited to reflect.

Comment: Like Arthur, I am surprised you are seeing failures with SLC SSDs. How sure are you that writing the logs is leading to the failures? In the case of engineers leaving the logging switched on, perhaps you could add an option for how long the logging is to be enabled with no "forever" choice.

Comment: Yes Andrew, we'd also considered 'timing out' the logging. I can't be positive that the logging is causing the issue and new information this morning seems to indicate two brands of which one brand is having more issues.

I guess the solution (if logging is causing the problem) is to queue and commit less regularly and have a timeout of the logging.

Comment: More details would help. Are you running an OS that supports TRIM (e.g. Win7 or higher)? Can you quantify what you mean by *a LOT of logging*? I.e. when logging is left on, what's the logging rate per second/minute/hour? And roughly what kind of total MB/GB get written per day or week? I suspect the logging rate might actually be the issue rather than MB/GB being written and I can explain that better in an answer - but lets get some ball-park numbers first if you can.

Answer (score 2):

OK I am pretty certain I have your answer.

From what I gather, `File.AppendAllText` is being used to write *each line* to the log file. This means the log file is being opened, written to, and closed every time `AppendAllText` is called.

Without looking at exactly how `AppendAllText` is implemented, we may as well assume that at best only the additional data is being written to disk plus corresponding meta-data (file-system stuff).

Thousands of iterations of the above, over a period of time, will indeed destroy a SSD (MLC types more quickly than SLC). That's because SSDs can only write to their internal storage in large blocks.

### Example

Take a 128GB SSD with an internal block size of 512KB. That's 262,144 blocks in total.

Putting it really simply, without even counting meta-data (file system) writes, if you open-write-close 262,144 tiny files you will have caused *every* block on the SSD to have been written to. Do that another 1000-4000 times (depending on SSD), and you've pretty much killed it.

Now I'm sure SSDs have clever stuff going on to minimize the above kind of wear, so take the example with a grain of salt. But the principal here is true and it matters: SSDs don't like millions of small writes.

Adding a line to a log file constitutes a small write of data (or maybe a big write, depending on how MS implemented things) and one or more small writes to update meta-data.

### Possible solutions

- Write to the log less frequently, say every 60 seconds, and/or...
- Open the log file as a `Stream`, append whatever you want in your loop, then flush/close the Stream. This approach means the file is only opened *once*, written to, then closed. .NET and the OS will optimize the write.
- Use a non-SSD hard drive for logging. If changing the logging code is not possible, but you can specify a logging path, then this might be the best option. Even a USB hard drive would do just fine! So long as it isn't SSD.